# Sidenav open on default instead of OnClick

Tags: javascript, html, css

I found this Sidenav on the internet which I would like to use for my application! Link to this: http://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_sidenav_none

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<style>
body {
    font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
}

.sidenav {
    display: none;
    height: 100%;
    width: 250px;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: #111;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    padding-top: 60px;
}

.sidenav a {
    padding: 8px 8px 8px 32px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 25px;
    color: #818181;
    display: block;
    transition: 0.3s
}

.sidenav a:hover, .offcanvas a:focus{
    color: #f1f1f1;
}

.sidenav .closebtn {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 25px;
    font-size: 36px;
    margin-left: 50px;
}

@media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
  .sidenav {padding-top: 15px;}
  .sidenav a {font-size: 18px;}
}
</style>
<body>

<div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
  <a href="#">About</a>
  <a href="#">Services</a>
  <a href="#">Clients</a>
  <a href="#">Contact</a>
</div>

<h2>Sidenav Example</h2>
<p>Click on the element below to open the side navigation menu.</p>
<span style="font-size:30px;cursor:pointer" onclick="openNav()">&#9776; open</span>

<script>
function openNav() {
    document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.display = "block";
}

function closeNav() {
    document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.display = "none";
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

But, the sidenav only opens when the button is activated, but I would like it to be open by default. What syntaxes would I need to change for this?

Comment: Did you try anything yourself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is remove the css that is hiding the sidenav by default

```
.sidenav {
    //display: none; - remove this line
    height: 100%;
    width: 250px;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: #111;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    padding-top: 60px;
}
```

Comment: Awesome! I will accept this answer as soon as possible